# Is there a function to get the client rect inside the Twebbrowser?

Tags: html, delphi, resize, twebbrowser

I'm not sure if I can explain this clearly.

I have some simple HTML code and am loading it to the Twebbrowser. Then, I want to get the Rect of my HTML output so that i could proper re-size the height of my Twebbrowser.

It's like auto-size feature, but it's only the height that auto-size.
is that possible?

thanx in advance...

Comment: If it's your HTML code then you can write a Javascript function and then use the function from Delphi.

Comment: Beware: resizing the browser can change the page layout and so the width and height of the document. Depending on your use case this might not be desirable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should get you started:

```
uses MSHTML, Math;

var
  HtmlElement, BodyElement:IHTMLElement2;
  PageWidth, PageHeight: Integer;
begin
  with WebBrowser1.ControlInterface do
  begin
    HtmlElement:=(Document as IHTMLDocument3).documentElement as IHTMLElement2;
    BodyElement:=(Document as IHTMLDocument2).body as IHTMLElement2;
  end;
  PageWidth:= Max(BodyElement.scrollWidth, HtmlElement.scrollWidth);
  PageHeight:= Max(BodyElement.scrollHeight, HtmlElement.scrollHeight);
end;
```

I read the dimensions both from the HTML element and the BODY element and take the maximum because often they have different dimensions. And even more often one of them returns size 0x0. This behavior also changes from browser version to browser version. It's a workaround, you have to check if this is the right way to deal with it in your use case.

Note: the image @Darkerstar posted was the old MSDN illustration for getting element dimensions. The updated version (for IE9) seems to be this one: [Measuring Element Dimension and Location with CSSOM in Internet Explorer 9](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530302%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

You can work out the page height inside TWebBrowser's document complete event, using document.body.scrollWidth and scrollHeight

[image: IE6 clientHeight etc]